# How to call an async method in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I'm trying to learn MVVM pattern in WPF application. I wrote this async method in my viewmodel (it has to be async since I'm using HttpClient and it's methods are async):

```
public async Task<Dictionary<int, BusStop>> GetBusStops()
    {
        var busStopDict = new Dictionary<int, BusStop>();
        var url = "my url";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var regularExpression = Regex.Match(data, "\\[(.)*\\]");
            var result = regularExpression.Groups[0];

            var json = JValue.Parse(result.ToString());
            var jsonArray = json.ToArray();

            foreach (var a in jsonArray)
            {
                // irrelevant logic

                busStopDict.Add(nr, bs);
            }
        }

        return busStopDict;
    }
```

This methods returns a dictionary filled with bus stops (my model). I would like to bind this dictionary with combobox in view, but I can't get it work, because I can't call this async method in constructor of my viewmodel and I have no idea where can I call it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why can´t you call the method in your constructor?

Comment: Constructor cannot be async so I can't await that method. And if I don't await that method it returns Task<> instead of Dictionary<>

Comment: Basically all you need to know about this is described quite well in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx. I suggest to read it instead of following the answers below.

Answer (score 8):

I would not recommend to write logic in your viewmodel constructor. Instead I would create an Loaded event trigger in your view also to ensure you do not interfere with the loading procedure of the view.

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"


<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Then in your viewmodel I recomend doing the following:

Add the following property for your Loaded event

```
public DelegateCommand LoadedCommand { get; }
```

Then assign it in your constructor

```
LoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync());
```

Add the loaded method and call your method within it

```
private async Task ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync()
{
    var busStops = await GetBusStops();
    //TODO: display the busStops or do something else
}
```

Furthermore is adding "Async" as suffix to your asynchron methods names a good naming pattern. It enables you to quickly see which methods are asynchron. (so rename "GetBusStops" to "GetBusStopsAsync")

This is a simple `DelegateCommand` implementation

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) 
               : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, 
               Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if( CanExecuteChanged != null )
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

When using this implementation you need to change your initialising of the `DelegateCommand` in your viewmodel constructor to the following

```
LoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand(async (param) => await ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync());
```

Comment: Do I have to implement DelegateCommand on my own? If so, how?

Comment: you can use the [prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) (proven practices for predictable results) library . or take a look at a simpler implementation [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/delegatecommand.html)

Comment: It's worth noting that methods Execute() and CanExecute() cannot be overriden as they are no more virtual methods.

Comment: (That link is 6 years old)

Comment: I recomend the microsoft implementation of [prism](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/)

Comment: I followed this article: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx) but I sometimes have null exception within AsyncCommandBase class in Execute method (with parameter). Do you know why?

Comment: doesn't it have most likely something to do with your code in the ExecuteMehod? I can't tell more about it without further informations. I would recommend to create a new so thread when you have a specific problem with your implementation

Comment: Microsoft no longer implements the Prism Library. It is developed by Brian Lagunas and Dan Siegel, who are doing a great job BTW keeping it current and performant. I used it on every project that I do in WPF.  https://github.com/prismlibrary

Answer (score 3):

You should use [asynchronous data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) (I have an entire article on the subject).

Using `NotifyTask` from [my Mvvm.Async library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async), it could look like this:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<int, BusStop>> GetBusStopsAsync() { ... }
public NotifyTask<Dictionary<int, BusStop>> BusStops { get; }

MyViewModelConstructor()
{
  BusStops = NotifyTask.Create(() => GetBusStopsAsync());
}
```

Then your view can model-bind to `BusStops.Result` to get the dictionary (or null if it isn't retrieved yet), and also data-bind to `BusStops.IsNotCompleted`/`BusStops.IsFaulted` for busy spinners / error indicators.

Answer (score 1):

Start your async method in the constructor and define an action to be continued with like.

```
//Constructor
public ViewModel()
{
    GetBusStops().ContinueWith((BusStops) =>
    {
        //This anonym method is called async after you got the BusStops
        //Do what ever you need with the BusStops
    });
}
```

Don´t forget to invoke the UI thread if you want to access an property used for the View with

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    //Your code here
});
```

Comment: is it a good practice to write code in your viewmodel constructor? also can't this way interfere with the loading procedure of the view?

Comment: You are initializing your ViewModel with loading the BusStops. Initialisation usually is done in the  constructor. Because the method is still async, you are not disturbing the loading of the View. Because the ContinueWith is not running in the UI thread, you possible have to use the invoke as shown in my answer.

Comment: but there is a reason it is async I supose. (shouldn't it be called more like "LoadBusStopsAsync"?) It's a blocking action. (should't those be handled different?) and I think in my solution you do not need to use the dispatcher

Comment: With this code, you are using the method async. Only the invocation is done in the constructor - because you need it during your initialisation.

Comment: I think it depends on your coding conventions. We do not write any logic in the constructor. We just assign the incected services to an private property for further use and any other stuff is done elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

I would check out **AsycLazy** or check out **AsyncCommands** and create a async Task based "LoadCommand". You shouldn't put much logic into a contructor as it will make it tougher to debug, forces you to strongly couple and will make it very difficult to write Unit tests for your view Model. I tend to make everything lazy if I can.

AsyncLazy 
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html

AsyncCommand 
http://mike-ward.net/2013/08/09/asynccommand-implementation-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's MVVM Community Toolkit has an implementation of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#handling-taskt-properties), and references the name NotifyTaskCompletion, the same name from [Stephen Cleary's 2014 Microsoft article on asynchronous data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding).

(Stephen Cleary also maintains his own  implementation of this, linked to from [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459383/3442232) to this same question.)